# C # DSM (Data Source Manager) is not displayed using NTWAIN library

Tags: c#, twain

I use the NTWAIN library, found a good solution for interacting with this library, modified it a little. This is actually it:

```
public class ScanningTwain
    {
        List<Image> ImagesScan;
        DataSource myDS;
        TwainSession session;

        public ScanningTwain()
        {
            ImagesScan = new List<Image>();
        }

        public List<Image> Scan(decimal dpi)
        {
            ImagesScan.Clear();
            
            var appId = TWIdentity.CreateFromAssembly(DataGroups.Image, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
           
            session = new TwainSession(appId);

            session.TransferReady += session_TransferReady;
            session.DataTransferred += session_DataTransferred;
            session.SourceDisabled += session_SourceDisable;

            session.Open();

            IEnumerable<DataSource> lesSources = session.GetSources();
            myDS = lesSources.FirstOrDefault();
            myDS.Open();
        
            PixelType typeCouleur = PixelType.Gray;

            if (myDS.Capabilities.ICapPixelType.CanSet &&
                myDS.Capabilities.ICapPixelType.GetValues().Contains(typeCouleur))
            {
                myDS.Capabilities.ICapPixelType.SetValue(typeCouleur);
            }

            TWFix32 DPI = (float)dpi;

            if (myDS.Capabilities.ICapXResolution.CanSet &&
                myDS.Capabilities.ICapXResolution.GetValues().Contains(DPI))
            {
                myDS.Capabilities.ICapXResolution.SetValue(DPI);
            }

            if (myDS.Capabilities.ICapYResolution.CanSet &&
                myDS.Capabilities.ICapYResolution.GetValues().Contains(DPI))
            {
                myDS.Capabilities.ICapYResolution.SetValue(DPI);
            }

            myDS.Enable(SourceEnableMode.ShowUI, false, System.IntPtr.Zero);

            EventWaitHandle session_SourceDisable_Wait = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
            session_SourceDisable_Wait.WaitOne();
            return ImagesScan;
        }

        void session_DataTransferred(object sender, NTwain.DataTransferredEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NativeData != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Bitmap img = null;
                //Need to save out the data.
                Stream s = e.GetNativeImageStream();
                BitmapSource bitmapsource = s.ConvertToWpfBitmap();

                using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
                    enc.Save(outStream);
                    img = new Bitmap(outStream);
                }

                if (img != null)
                {
                    ImagesScan.Add(img);
                }
            }
        }

        void session_SourceDisable(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myDS.Close();
            session.Close();
        }

        void session_TransferReady(object sender, NTwain.TransferReadyEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

The error occurs at the line: `myDS.Open ()` ; in the `public List <Image> Scan (decimal dpi)`  method writes that `myDS = null` , I suppose this is due to the fact that when this line is executed `session.Open ()` ; DSM does not appear so that you can select a scanner. Although I downloaded DSM from the official site. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: 32-bit processes will only show 32-bit DSMs, 64-bit processes will only show 64-bit DSMs. Most TWAIN drivers are 32-bit only. Therefore change your project configuration from “Any CPU” or “64-bit” to “32-bit”.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. But now there is an error on the line `myDS.Enable (SourceEnableMode.ShowUI, false, System.IntPtr.Zero);` "System.NullReferenceException" what could be the reason?

Comment: What is the complete stack trace of the null reference exception?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException
    HResult = 0x80004003
    Message = Object reference does not point to an instance of an object.
    Source = NTwain
    Stack trace:
     at NTwain.MessageLoopHook.Rethrow (ex exception)
     at NTwain.Internals.InternalMessageLoopHook.Invoke (Action)
     at NTwain.TwainSession.NTwain.Internals.ITwainSessionInternal.EnableSource (SourceEnableMode, Boolean Modal, IntPtr windowHandle)
     at NTwain.DataSource.Enable (SourceEnableMode, Boolean Modal, IntPtr windowHandle)
     at NsgSoft_Trade.ScanningTwain.Scan (Decimal dpi) at C: \ ...